# Unable to download Red Hat CodeReady Studio in eclipse

Tags: jboss-developer-studio

I am trying to install Red Hat CodeReady Studio from eclipse marketplace but I keep getting the below error:

```
Unable to read repository at <https://devstudio.redhat.com/12/stable/composite/12.9.0/content.xml>

Error Stack  

    javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:575)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Any Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have tried latest Eclipse(2019-12) and installed CRS 12.13.0.GA without issues.
Which Eclipse version have you tried?
It looks like like you are trying to install quite old version of CRS.

Josef

PS: You can use JIRA for reporting issues with CRS: https://issues.redhat.com/projects/JBDS/ or witj JBoss Tools https://issues.redhat.com/projects/JBIDE/